# substitutions to homogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $ae\neq bc$
Then we can substitute

$y'=F(\frac{ax+by+c}{dx+ex+f})$ 
by $x=z-h $   ,$ y=w-k$ to a homogeneous equation.

In this problem I have tried to replace with the substitutions but I did not get anything.

Example $y'=\frac{x+y+4}{x-y-6}$

My solution: $X=\alpha +x$ 
and $Y=y+\beta$

$x+\alpha +y+\beta=x+y+4$ so $\alpha +\beta =4$

And $x=\alpha -y-\beta=x-y-6$ so $ \alpha -\beta=-6$
From here I get $ \alpha=-1$ and $\beta=5$

From there I get $y'=\frac{X+Y}{X-Y}$

here From X=ZY substitution We can solve the equation..

Comment: Do you know what's the point of this transformation? Also, the condition is $ae \neq bd$.

Comment: No. And I have no idea about the condition.

Comment: The point of this transformations is to get rid of constant terms in numerator and denominator to get equation of type $y' = F \left ( \frac{Ax+By}{Cx + Dy} \right )$ which is homogeneous and can be solved via substitution $y(x) = x \cdot z(x)$. To get rid of the constant terms we can simply make a coordinate shift; after that we get system of linear equations and $ae \neq bd$ is the condition for this system to be non-degenerate.

Comment: I have added some more. Would you look at them? But still I do not understand why the condition is neccesary?